# NullPointerException inside if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception, javafx, runtime-error

Recently I have been working on a calculator, using java and javafx. I have been making conditions for my events, but I am getting a NullPointerException. Now here are the values:

```
Boolean eventTest;
String stringX, stringY;
```

stringX will already be defined when I run this.

After using the debugger it came down to this line of code:

```
if(eventTest == false & stringY == null & stringX != null||eventTest == false & stringY != null & stringX != null)
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at calculator$3.handle(calculator.java:263)
at calculator$3.handle(calculator.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The question is **Why do I get a NullPointerException from this line of code, and how can I fix it?**

Thanks.

Comment: Do you meant to perform a bitwise `&` operation or do you mean `&&` (and) instead?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Single-character operators on booleans aren't bitwise. They just don't short-circuit.

Comment: Some one vote to close giving reason a funny reason... I think if you don't understand the question better to leave a comment or keep away from that.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a clearly-stated question. Subtle problem, but everything needed is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Boolean`, with a capital, is a wrapper class, and the variable's default value is null. You probably just need a primitive `boolean`. If there's a particular reason you need the wrapper, initialize it.

Answer (score 3):

Check if `eventTest` is `null`. Since `Boolean` allows `null` values.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code scares me :

```
if(eventTest == false 
  & stringY == null & stringX != null ||
  eventTest == false & stringY != null & stringX != null)
```

Have you even realized that in both condition of the `||` you do the same validation ?

Anyway, this is not the point.

`eventTest` is a **B**oolean, so it is an Object, which means it is null if not initialized so it can throw an NPE if not validated before checking for false/true value.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
 eventTest == false // default value of a Java object is null
```

`eventTest` is `Boolean` object type and it's default value is `null`.

So `eventTest` is `null` and fail to unbox `null` to `boolean` so you will get `NullPointerException`.

[Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) may help you to understand what is happen here.

Here from type `Boolean` to type `boolean` unboxing happen as If r is a reference of type `Boolean`, then unboxing conversion converts `r` into `r.booleanValue()`

When `r` is `null`. you will get `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

eventTest == false  will cause the [unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) of eventTest ,and if it is null ,you
get NullPointer Exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using object's value for comparison, its better to use equals method than using `==`. The following code can overcome your problem:

```
if((eventTest != null && eventTest == false) & stringY == null & stringX != null || (eventTest != null && eventTest == false) & stringY != null & stringX != null)
```

`eventTest == false` can eventually be written as `bol.equals(false)` or `bol.booleanValue() == false` after checking for null `eventTest != null`.

If you are not convinced with the above code declare eventTest as primitive boolean: 

`boolean eventTest;`